# Split vector into several vectors depending on its content

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

I have a vector that I know will consist of the values 100, 200 and 400. The values will not be mixed up but be it order, for example

```
target = [100 100 100 100 200 200 400 400 400];
```

I want to split this vector up into three vectors, each vector containing all the values of that kind.

```
A = [100 100 100 100];
B = [200 200];
C = [400 400 400];
```

The length of target will change from time to time and so will the proportion of 100, 200 and 400.

How can I make this split in an easy way?

My own solution looks like this but I was thinking that there is another way that requires less code.

```
columns = size(target, 2);

A = [];
B = [];
C = [];
% Splitting target into groups
for j = 1:columns
    if target(1, j) == 100
        A = [A, 100];
    elseif target(1, j) == 200
        B = [B, 200];
    elseif target(1,j) == 400
        C = [C, 400];
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something simpler:

```
target=[100 100 100 100 200 200 400 400 400];

A = target(target==100)
B = target(target==200)
C = target(target==400)
```

How this works: `target==x` returns a logical array of size equal to `target`. Then you can use that logical array to index `target`.

Comment: Seems like all solutions work good but I'm going with the simple solution! At least for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A little more generic approach:

```
%// find and count unique elements
[a,b] = hist(target,unique(target));

%// Create vectors according to target and number occurences and store them in cell array
temp = arrayfun(@(x,y) y*ones(x,1),a,b,'uni',0)
```

an alternative and probably faster approach would be:

```
%// get indices of unique values
[~,~,c] = unique(target)
%// Create vectors according to indices and store them in cell array
temp = accumarray(c(:),target(:),[],@(x) {x})
```

**I personally would recommend you to stop at this point and continue with the cell array!**

If you know how many unique elements there are and you *really* want to store them in separate variables, you can use:

```
[A,B,C] = temp{:}
```

---

**The most generic and error prone approach I could think of, would be:**

```
%// create a map container with all values you're expecting and it's corresponding specifier
valueSet =   {'A', 'B', 'C'};
keySet = [100 200 400];
mapObj = containers.Map(keySet,valueSet)

%// create a struct and distribute keys to specifier
for ii = 1:numel(keySet);
   out.(mapObj(keySet(ii))) = target(target == keySet(ii));
end
```

You get a struct `out` with the fields `A`, `B` and `C`:

The interesting part is, that you could also generate the `keySet` and `valueSet` automatically:

```
%// keySet are all unique values of target
keySet = unique(target)
%// create specifiers according to number of unique elements
valueSet = cellstr(char(65:65+numel(keySet)-1).') %'
%// you get 'A' 'B' and 'C' to use as field names
```

This way you don't need to know which are your elements and how many different ones you actually have. The only difference to your original request is that you don't get the variables `A`, `B` and `C` but `out.A`, `out.B` and `out.C`

[image]

Comment: Ha ha. Love the alternative approach ... but ouch for readability. This is were commenting code makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it using `diff` and `find`.

```
clear
clc
close all

target=[100 100 100 100 200 200 400 400 400];

%// Form vector containing cumulative differences from consecutive elements
DiffVector = [-Inf diff([target Inf])];
```

`DiffVector` looks like this:

```
DiffVector =

  -Inf     0     0     0   100     0   200     0     0   Inf


%// Find where values are not equal to 0. That's the starting indices of
%each sequence of numbers of interest.
indices = find(DiffVector~=0)
```

`indices` looks like this:

```
indices =

     1     5     7    10

%// Put every sequence in its own cell.
v = cell(1,numel(indices)-1);
for k = 1:numel(indices)-1
    v{k} = target(indices(k):idx(k+1)-1);
end
```

Display the content of the cell array

```
celldisp(v)

v{1} =

   100   100   100   100



v{2} =

   200   200



v{3} =

   400   400   400
```

You can combine the first 2 steps into only one for simplicity.

Yay!

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way: sort and then split into cells using `mat2cell`:

```
st = sort(target);
result = mat2cell(st, 1, diff([0 find(diff(st)) numel(st)]));
```